# How to model Betting/Accounting BoundedContexts when betting relies heavily on account balance?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, event-sourcing, bounded-contexts

Lets say you have an application where you can create a bet on a coin toss. Your account has a balance that was funded with your credit card.

The sequence of events is the following:

> 1. POST /coin_toss_bets { amount: 5 USD }
> 2. Start transaction/acquire locks inside the Bet subdomain useCase
> 3. Does the user have enough balance? (check accounting aggregate balance projection of the users deposits)
> 4. Debit the users account for the amount for 5 USD
> 5. Create bet/flip the coin to get a result
> 6. Payout the user if they bet on the correct side
> 7. Commit transaction
> 8. UI layer is given the bet and displays an animation

My question is how this can be modeled with 2 separate BoundedContexts (betting/accounting). Its said that database transactions should not cross a BoundedContext since they can be located on different machines/microservices, but in this scenario, the use case of creating a bet heavily relies on a non-dirty read of the users projected account balance (strong consistency).

There is also no way to perform a compensating action if the account is overdebited, since the UI layer is requiring that the bet is created atomically.

Is there any way to do this with CQRS/Event Sourcing that doesn't require asking for the users account balance inside the betting subdomain? Or would you always have to ensure that the balance projection is correct inside this transaction (they must be deployed together)?

Answer (score 0):

Ensuring that the account has sufficient balance for a transaction seems to be an invariant business rule in your case. So let us assume that it cannot be violated.

Then the question is simply about how to handle "transactions" that span across boundary contexts.

DDD does say that transactions (invariant boundaries) should not cross a Bounded Context (BC). The rule is applicable even at the level of aggregates. But the correct way to read it would be transaction as part of a "Single Request."

The best way to deal with this scenario is to simply accept the request from UI to place a bet and return a "202 Accepted" status message, along with a unique job tracker ID. The only database interaction during request processing should be to persist the data into a "Jobs" table and probably trigger a "BET_PLACED" domain event.

You would then process the Bet asynchronously. Yes, the processing would still involve calling the Accounts bounded context, but through its published API. Since you are not in the context of a request anymore, the processing time need not fit into usual constraints.

Once the processing is completed, either the UI would refresh the page at regular intervals and update the user, or you can send a Push Notification to the browser.